# Trying to get the output of a command that run in the background

Tags: linux, bash

If I run the command  `cat -v /dev/ttyUSB0 > output &` in the console and then send another command `echo -e '\xff\x09\x00' > /dev/ttyUSB0` I get the output. If I run the script bellow I do not get the output. How can I fix this?

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Connect to the specified device instead of stdin.
    stty -F /dev/$PortName $BaudRate cs8 -cstopb -parenb -icanon min 1 time 1

    # Run in background the process that will listen to the output.
    cat -v /dev/$PortName > output &

    # Turn on/off and receive status of the relays.
    case "$1" in
                   "1:1")
                          echo -e '\xff\x01\x01' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "1:0")
                          echo -e '\xff\x01\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "2:1")
                          echo -e '\xff\x02\x01' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "2:0")
                          echo -e '\xff\x02\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "3:1")
                          echo -e '\xff\x03\x01' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "3:0")
                          echo -e '\xff\x03\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "4:1")
                          echo -e '\xff\x04\x01' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "4:0")
                          echo -e '\xff\x04\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "5:1")
                          echo -e '\xff\x05\x01' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "5:0")
                          echo -e '\xff\x05\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "6:1")
                          echo -e '\xff\x06\x01' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "6:0")
                          echo -e '\xff\x06\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "7:1")
                          echo -e '\xff\x07\x01' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "7:0")
                          echo -e '\xff\x07\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "8:1")
                          echo -e '\xff\x08\x01' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "8:0")
                          echo -e '\xff\x08\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   "status-all")
                          echo -e '\xff\x09\x00' > /dev/$PortName

                          ;;
                   *)
                          echo "Select Case problem."
                          echo "Usage: $MODULE <param>"

                          exit 1
    esac

    # Exit app.
    exit
```

Comment: Every time you run that script you stomp all over (and truncate) your output file.

Comment: You don't show `PortName="ttyUSB0"` or equivalent in your code; have you set it?  Similarly with `BaudRate`, though that may be less critical. What do you see when you run with `bash -x your-script.sh` (with appropriate arguments, if there are any)?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I'm not showing the entire script but the script works fine.  When I run `bash -x my_script status-all` I see every script steps but but not get anything from `cat -v /dev/$PortName > output &`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the entire script http://pastebin.com/HfUSeVxB

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) -- two names and links for the same basic idea.  You've done a lot of the work needed, but fixing 'undefined' variables by simple assignments in your reduced script helps convince us that maybe your script as shown produces the effect shown.  Note that if you can't reproduce the problem in a reduced script, it suggests that what you're removing is part of the trouble; it gives focus to your investigation.

Comment: I'll also observe that you can surely eliminate most of your `case` statement by splitting the pattern (into `$hi` and `$lo`, say) and using something like: `codes=( $'\x00' $'\x01' $'\x02' $'\x03' $'\x04' $'\x05' $'\x06' $'\x07' $'\x08' )` and  `printf '%c%c%c\n' $'\xFF' "${codes[$hi]}" "${codes[$lo]}"` or variants of that theme.